# Unity3D Screen api resturned wrong resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an issue 2 days ago as the title above.
I tried Screen.width, Screen.currentResolution.width, Display.main.systemWidth but it was returned unexpected result.
tested on note8, s7, s7+, s6, s5, moto x gen 1
some device run android 6, and some run android 7
tried with DisplayMetrics class via AndroidJavaClass Unity.
Example: I want get note resolution: the expected result: 1440w x 2960h, but it give me 810w x 1440h
with AndroidJavaClass: 
- Density: 1.96875 
- Density dpi: 315 
- Width px: 810 
- Height px: 1440 
- Scaled density: 1.96875 
- xDpi: 290 
- yDpi: 292 
Any help pls?